# Android Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent pass value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have button in a fragment, which upon click should check if data exists in firebase db or not. Below is the function in a separate class file that will be called on button click in an async task.

How can I return boolean value true/false from addListenerForSingleValueEvent back to the fragment async task?

```js
void checkDataExists(final String mobile){
DatabaseReference fireDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(context.getString(R.string.app_name);

fireDBRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 String mob = 
     String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(context.getString(R.string.tracked_mobile))
                             .getValue());
                             
                //compare the strings mobile 
                 boolean match = mobile.equals(mob);

                // return match value to fragment to update the view.
                }

                 @Override
                 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                     Log.w(TAG + "/checkDataExists","Data read from DB failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                 }
             });
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have case like this, and I create my own callback like:

```
public interface IMyCallback {
    void onSuccess(boolean isExist);
    void onFailure(String error);
}
```

now when I call function `checkDataExists` it looks like:

```
checkDataExists(mobile, new ISingUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(boolean isExist) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String error) {

                }
            });
```

And in your check you need to make changes like:

```
    void checkDataExists(final String mobile, final IMyCallback callback){
    DatabaseReference fireDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    fireDBRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     String mob = 
         String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(context.getString(R.string.tracked_mobile))
                                 .getValue());

                    //compare the strings mobile 
                     boolean match = mobile.equals(mob);

                    // return match value to fragment to update the view.
                    callback.onSuccess(match);
                    }

                     @Override
                     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                         callback.onFailure(databaseError.getMessage());
                     }
                 });
             }
```

Comment: Thanks....just one thing...databaseError.getException() doesn't work..... it has to be databaseError.getMessage() or databaseError.getDetails()